# AMD different ways to install drivers

Tags: 12.04, ati, bash, radeon

I do not want to know how to install drivers but what the differences between 2 ways and which one is better.

1. building deb files from `*.run` file

   ```
   sudo sh*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
   ```

   installing created deb files

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
2. directly installing `*.run` files

   ```
   sudo bash *.run
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Creating .deb files has (at least) two advantages:

One is, that it's pretty easy to uninstall them using standard tools like apt-get or synaptic.

The other is, that by using .deb files, the AMD driver is added to DKMS list. This means, that the AMD drivers kernel module is always automatically reinstalled after every kernel update. When directly installing, I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that you have to reinstall the AMD driver after every kernel update manually.